# Ember Js and Sails js AND clause in controller

Tags: ember.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm working on a project with Ember.js and Sails.js now i'm having an issue
in my controller,

i want to run a computed query and use "AND" clause but i don't know how to
do it, i tried to google it but had no luck

here is my controller

```
selectedDepartment: Ember.computed(function (){
  return this.get('store').query('service', {
    where : {
      department : this.get('department.id'),
      isPublic : true
      }
   })
})
```

It's getting me crazy i mean what is wrong here ?

Comment: query return Promise and Computed property are not Promise aware. You can go through [igniter article](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/) to make it promise aware.

Comment: Okay I'm kind of new to Ember .. what do you mean by [igniter article] ?

Comment: I forgot to include the link. now I updated [link](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/) in the above comments. Instead of making computed property to promise aware, you can look for other alternative options.

Comment: @kumkanillam store methods return PromiseObject/PromiseArray objects.

Comment: @locks Now only I am seeing the difference here in api doc said `returns Promise promise` that's the PromiseProxy objects ...Is `Promise promise` === PromiseProxy objects ? In all of my answer, I used to say it returns `Promise` Hope I will change it one day

Comment: @Haboosh What is the problem here? Could you explain what's the problem of your code? Is there no output? Do you see an error on your console? Is your query code returning the wrong data set?

Comment: @Timm it doesn't show any results like if the query isn't working at all but if i deleted either the first or second condition it works like charm, my question is how could i use the "AND" clause in such case :(